# Flutter - How to change the name of the application depending on the language of the phone

Tags: android, flutter

I want to change the name of my App depending on the language of the user's device.

I know that app's name is located in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Flutter_app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

But i don't know how to change `android:label` dinamically.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a reference in your every `strings.xml` locale file as below:

```
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
```

And use it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` application section:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```